# convert a specific value to the value between [0 1] in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a range of values as [12,540  108  201,120  17] in an array.

I am going to convert these values in a range of [0 1] in MATLAB.

Is there any function in MATLAB?

Comment: division is not available in your version of MATLAB? I.e., dividing by the maximum element, or the maximum expected element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [mapminmax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mapminmax.html) function from Neural Network Toolbox.

With this function you can map you data into `[YMIN YMAX]` interval:

```
[Y,PS] = mapminmax(X,YMIN,YMAX)
```

It returns mapping parameters allowing you to use the same mapping with the new data:

```
Y = mapminmax('apply',X,PS)
```

or to revert the mapping to get your data back to the original space:

```
X = mapminmax('reverse',Y,PS)
```

But if you don't need to apply the same mapping twice or to revert it, then it's easier just to divide your data by the maximum value:

```
Y = (X - min(X)) / (max(X) - min(X))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all values are positive (as in your example) and the relationship between the variables in the original array and the [0 1] array is linear:

```
 x = [12,540 108 201,120 17];
 y = x/max(x);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
[Y,PS] = mapminmax(X,0,1)
```

Define your variable as `x` which can be matrix and use above comment in your code.